# What is the difference between docker-desktop, docker-desktop-data and my WSL distro Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

Command `wsl --list --verbose` returns the following list on my Windows machine:

```
$ wsl --list --verbose
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

I have installed Docker Desktop on my machine.  What is the difference between `docker-desktop`, `docker-desktop-data` and my WSL distro `Ubuntu`? Should `Ubuntu` not be selected as my WSL distribution?

P.S. If I select another entry from list with `wsl --setdefault <name-of-distro>` I do not notice significant changes. It confuses me more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should Ubuntu not be selected as my wsl?

Yes, it should.  First up, I would recommend:

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

Your example in the question was missing the hyphen, so that may be why it didn't have any effect.

This should change the default distribution to Ubuntu.  Without that, the `wsl` command (by itself, or with many arguments) will fail, since `docker-desktop-data` is not designed to be booted.  See WSL issue [#8727](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8727) for some more detail on that.

The problem often happens when Docker Desktop is installed before Ubuntu, or when Ubuntu was never properly set as default.

After setting it as default, confirm it with `wsl -l -v` again.

Then a simple `wsl` should start Ubuntu.

> What is the difference between `docker-desktop`, `docker-desktop-data` and my WSL distro `Ubuntu`?

- `Ubuntu` is the WSL distribution here for daily use.  It doesn't have to be Ubuntu, but that is the default with WSL.  This is where you should install packages and run your normal shell.
- `docker-desktop` is a distribution supplied and managed by Docker Desktop that contains the Docker Engine.  When started, Docker Desktop will start both `Ubuntu` and `docker-desktop`, injecting some links into Ubuntu so that it will be able to use the `docker` commands correctly.

  `docker-desktop` is *managed* by the Docker Desktop application.  You shouldn't modify it.  Any changes you make will likely be lost the next time Docker Desktop upgrades.
- `docker-desktop-data` is a [non-bootable](https://superuser.com/a/1613591/1210833) distribution that contains Docker volumes, containers, images, etc.  It is also managed by Docker Desktop.

Comment: The command ```wsl --setdefault <name-of-distro>``` is accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69209097/12501050 and it worked for me. I.e. I could confirm it with ```wsl -l -v```. Maybe it is deprecated?